# How to convert scala immutable map to JSON using Java?

Tags: java, scala

How to convert scala immutable map to JSON using Java?

I have the following example

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> statesMap = scala.collection.immutable.Map("AL" -> "Alabama", "AK" -> "Alaska")
```

and I need to convert this to JSON using Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend use Google [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for it:

In that case, type the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
String convertedMap = gson.toJson(statesMap).toString();
```

Comment: is .toString() necessary since gson.toJson returns a string ?

Comment: No. Just thinking for printing and testing it

Comment: for some reason it didn't quite work with two lines you posted

Comment: Well, I should work for any Object, but maybe I've underestimate Scala. If is inmutable... is it really neccesary scala Object? You can just create ImmutableMap<String, String> using Google guava library. That works for sure